# CS0305, Invalid number of arguments when using System.Func delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I get following error:

```
error CS0305: Using the generic type 
'System.Func<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,TResult>' 
requires '10' type arguments
```

On this line:

```
public static IDoubleArray ApplyFunc(IDoubleArray inputArray1, 
                          IDoubleArray inputArray2, 
                           Func<double, double, double> f) {
```

The Func definition in the System namespace looks like this:

```
[TypeForwardedFrom("System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, 
                    Culture=Neutral,      
                    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
public delegate TResult 
       Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

Everything looks fine, but compiler doesn't think so.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks.

edit:

The call looks like this:

```
/// <summary>Inverse cumulative distribution function</summary> 
        /// <param name="p">Probabilities at which to compute the inverse cdf</param>
        /// <param name="mu">Scale parameters</param>
        public static IDoubleArray Inv(IDoubleArray p, IDoubleArray mu)
        {
            return ArrayMath.ApplyFunc(Matrix.ConvertToMatrix(p), Matrix.ConvertToMatrix(mu), Inv);
        }
```

Comment: What's the call to ApplyFunc look like

Comment: are you sure the error message is not `The best overloaded method match for '...ApplyFunc(IDoubleArray, IDoubleArray, System.Func<double,double,double>)' has some invalid arguments...` ?

Comment: because `Inv` function you're passing to `ApplyFunc` has a signature = `(IDoubleArray, IDoubleArray, IDoubleArray)` and `ApplyFunc` needs `(double, double, double)` or am I off track?

Comment: ApplyFunc has signature (IDoubleArray, IDoubleArray, Func<double, double, double>). There is another Inv function with signature (double, double). But that is not the problem. The error is generated at the ApplyFunction definition so the call doesn't matter. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was the target wasn't .NET 4.0.